# How to route through VPN only for one IP (OSX)?

Tags: macos, vpn, routing

I've gotta use a VPN as the first in several hoop-jumps into a client system, but this kills all other networking for me, which makes it very hard to get any work done :(

I only need to use the VPN for VNC/Rdesktop connection to a specific IP address, and I want all my other network traffic to go over my normal wifi / en1 / vmnet / etc. I know the answer is somewhere in `route` but can't figure it out based on the documentation I can find.

I've tried this as a starting point once the VPN is connected:

```
sudo route add -net 10.255.99.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev utun1
```

But I get no response, and have to <kbd>ctrl-c</kbd> to get back to my terminal.

So in summation, I want to do two things to the (with VPN) routing table:

- Send all traffic to one IP (or 10.255.99.* if that's easier) to utun1
- Remove all the other routes that point to utun1, or stop utun1 from being the default gateway somehow?